# Plot multiple values as ranges - matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to determine the most efficient way to produce a group of `line` `plots` displayed as a range. I'm hoping to produce something like:

[image]

I'll try explain as much as possible. Sorry if I miss any information. I'm envisaging the `x-axis` to be a range `timestamps` of `hours` (8am-9am-10am etc). The total range would be between 8:00:00 and 27:00:00. The `y-axis` is a `count` of values occurring at any point in time. The range in the `plot` would represent the `max`, `min`, and `average` values occurring.

An example `df` is listed below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
    'Time1' : ['8:00:00','9:30:00','9:40:00','10:25:00','12:30:00','1:31:00','1:35:00','2:45:00','4:50:00'],                 
    'Occurring1' : ['1','2','3','4','5','5','6','6','7'],           
    'Time2' : ['8:10:00','9:34:00','9:48:00','10:40:00','1:30:00','2:31:00','3:35:00','3:45:00','4:55:00'],                 
    'Occurring2' : ['1','2','2','3','4','5','5','6','7'], 
    'Time3' : ['9:00:00','9:34:00','9:58:00','10:45:00','10:50:00','12:31:00','1:35:00','2:15:00','3:55:00'],                 
    'Occurring3' : ['1','2','3','4','4','5','6','7','8'],                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

So this `df` represents 3 different sets of `data`. The times, values occurring and even number of entries can vary.

Below is an initial example. Although I'm unsure if I need to rethink my approach. Would a rolling equation work here? Something that assesses the `max`, `min`, `avg` number of values occurring for each hour in a `df` (8:00:00-9:00:00).

Below is a full initial attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
    'Time1' : ['8:00:00','9:30:00','9:40:00','10:25:00','12:30:00','1:31:00','1:35:00','2:45:00','4:50:00'],                 
    'Occurring1' : ['1','2','3','4','5','5','6','6','7'],           
    'Time2' : ['8:10:00','9:34:00','9:48:00','10:40:00','1:30:00','2:31:00','3:35:00','3:45:00','4:55:00'],                 
    'Occurring2' : ['1','2','2','3','4','5','5','6','7'], 
    'Time3' : ['9:00:00','9:34:00','9:58:00','10:45:00','10:50:00','12:31:00','1:35:00','2:15:00','3:55:00'],                 
    'Occurring3' : ['1','2','3','4','4','5','6','7','8'],                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))

ax.plot(df['Time1'], df['Occurring1'])
ax.plot(df['Time2'], df['Occurring2'])
ax.plot(df['Time3'], df['Occurring3'])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result, you'd need to jump through a few hoops. First you need to create a regular time grid, onto which you interpolate the y-data (the occurrences). Then, you can get the min, max, and mean of the interpolated data. The code below demonstrates how to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Example data
d = ({
    'Time1' : ['8:00:00','9:30:00','9:40:00','10:25:00','12:30:00','1:31:00','1:35:00','2:45:00','4:50:00'],
    'Occurring1' : ['1','2','3','4','5','5','6','6','7'],
    'Time2' : ['8:10:00','9:34:00','9:48:00','10:40:00','1:30:00','2:31:00','3:35:00','3:45:00','4:55:00'],
    'Occurring2' : ['1','2','2','3','4','5','5','6','7'],
    'Time3' : ['9:00:00','9:34:00','9:58:00','10:45:00','10:50:00','12:31:00','1:35:00','2:15:00','3:55:00'],
    'Occurring3' : ['1','2','3','4','4','5','6','7','8'],
})

# Create dataframe, explicitly define dtypes
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.astype({
    "Time1": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring1": np.int,
    "Time2": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring2": np.int,
    "Time3": np.datetime64,
    "Occurring3": np.int,
})

# Create 1D vectors of time data
all_times = df[["Time1", "Time2", "Time3"]].values

# Representation of 1 minute in time
t_min = np.timedelta64(int(60*1e9), "ns")
# Create a regular time grid with 10 minute spacing
time_grid = np.arange(all_times.min(), all_times.max(), 10*t_min, dtype="datetime64")

# Storage buffer for interpolated occurring data
occurrences_grid = np.zeros((3, len(time_grid)))

# Loop over all occurrence data and interpolate to regular grid
for i in range(3):
    occurrences_grid[i] = griddata(
        points=df["Time%i" % (i+1)].values.astype("float"),
        values=df["Occurring%i" % (i+1)],
        xi=time_grid.astype("float"),
        method="linear"
    )

# Get min, max, and mean values of interpolated data
occ_min = np.min(occurrences_grid, axis=0)
occ_max = np.max(occurrences_grid, axis=0)
occ_mean = np.mean(occurrences_grid, axis=0)

# Plot interpolated data
plt.fill_between(time_grid, occ_min, occ_max, color="slategray")
plt.plot(time_grid, occ_mean, c="white")
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result (x-labels not formatted properly):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MPA. This is great. Would `timedelta` work instead of `datetime`?

Comment: @user9639519 The time format in the dataframe can be anything, but the `griddata` function only accepts floats or integers as an input, so the input needs to be converted prior to interpolation.